# SOAP v2 api "The operation has timed out"

Tags: magento-1.9, product, soap-api-v2

We are running a product update from a custom .net API via the SOAP connector in Magento 1.9.

After about 3 hours we get the following error

> The operation has timed out SKU 6X2XXXX9030

I can not find an error in the Apache log or the system.log in Magento

UPDATE:Client shared this error

> 19 records threw the error.. last timeout found 29/09/2015 13:11:54
>   Unable to connect to the remote server SKU jk5825jkk37k3

The php timeout

```
[root@magento log]# php -i | grep max_exec
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try the following:

Session SQL:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data(path, value)
VALUES ('web/cookie/cookie_lifetime', 86400)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 86400;
```

or manual:

- System -> Configuration
- General > Web
- Session Cookie management
- Cookie Lifetime: 86400

API SQL:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data(path, value)
VALUES ('api/config/session_timeout', 86400)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 86400;
```

or manual:

- System -> Configuration
- General > Services
- Magento Core Api
- General Settings
- Client Session timeout (sec.): 86400